# File permissions

Tags: files

Recently moved to WSL and Ubuntu and my Drupal 8 project has a specific issue with the JS and CSS cache files. When I click Aggregate js and css in performance the site breaks. Used Drush to update the db and clear cache multiple times. I am sure it is a file permission/access issues as the database is unable to update the .gz files. The files permission have been set to the standard settings inside the default and files folder but this makes no difference. What potentially are the other areas to check?

Comment: Did you recursively set your files permission ? Maybe the subfolder used to store the .gz files doesn't have the good permission

Comment: Hopefully you're using WLS2 and not WSL1. Anyways, it's similar like when in Drupal you create a user role, you add a bunch of permissions to it, but you never assign it to a user. So obviously, your user won't be able to do what you expect. Same thing here, you need to assign the appropriate Owner/Group to the folder so the server owns it. `cd /sites/default` and if you do `ls -l` you can see who is the owner/group (3rd and 4th columns). Then do `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R files`.